# Why extra words in birchat ha hodesh in Israel?

Tags: tefilla, eretz-yisrael

Some siddurim (e.g., in the Koren but not in the Artscroll) have extra words in the last paragraph, to be said in Israel, asking for additional blessings, including rain.  Why do we who are outside Israel not need or want these blessings, and why ask for rain in Israel every month, despite the seasonal rain patterns in Israel?

Comment: Isn't that just the Nusach Sefard version?

Comment: The longer version is the one recited by Sephardim (and nusach sepharad). Presumably, the Ashkenazi community in Israel adopted this custom from the local Sephardic community (along with a number of other customs)

Comment: @JoelK TY. any thoughts on Why do we who are outside Israel not need or want these blessings, and why ask for rain in Israel every month, despite the seasonal rain patterns in Israel?

Comment: @YehudaW I don't think it's a matter of needing or wanting extra blessings, as much as different versions of prayers evolving in different communities. FWIW some are opposed to adding numerous requests in birchat hachodesh as inappropriate for shabbat.

Comment: @YehudaW What I've observed in Israel is that the phrase requesting rain is actually only recited during the winter, when rain is beneficial. (Though I am aware that there are some who recite it year round.)

Comment: Rain, of course, is important anywhere in the world. But, our focus is mainly for the plentitude of Israel. The blessings of *Tal* and *Geshem* are focused on the seasons on Israel, not for Diaspora. I would also surmise that the whole concept of Rosh Hodesh declaration itself initiated (in terms of Sanhedrin, and later, via Hillel II's fixed calendar) in Israel.